# How to create and animate real 3d image in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, animation

This site: [www.sennep.com](http://www.sennep.com/) has a cool image on the left side of the full homepage (I use Mozilla browser on Ubuntu) that rotates.

How can I use animation capabilities of WPF (or in combination with other tools) to produce an effect like such animation on [www.sennep.com](http://www.sennep.com/) (for example, create something like a 3d car such that you can see the front, under-side, rear, etc)

Thanks.

Comment: There are some examples on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752064(v=vs.110).aspx) and on other resources. What have you already tried and what has failed?

Comment: The "starting point" is the "question"... I am checking the MSDN link you gave. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is plenty of tools which can help you :

- [helix](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/) toolkit it works independent of WPF
- [XNA](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38301/XNA-integration-inside-WPF)